# wp-cli core install --skip-email and --skip-config flags not working on MAMP unknown parameter

Tags: multisite, wp-cli, core, local-installation

This command

```
wp core multisite-install --url="dev3.XXXXXXX.wp" --title="XXXX" --admin_user="XXXXXadmin" --admin_password="XXXXX123" --admin_email="XXXX@XXXX.com" --skip-email --skip-config
```

Creates this error

```
Error: Parameter errors:
 unknown --skip-config parameter
```

If I remove the `--skip-config` flag it then gives me the same error for the `--skip-email` flag. This command works with out error on AWS EC2. Why is this command have a different behavior on OSX that Linux? Thanks.

Comment: Different versions of wp-cli maybe?

Comment: Good idea - downloaded latest using composer 0.25 - still same result